# Can codepush update happens when first time open an app?

Tags: react-native, react-native-code-push

By default, when opening an app for the first time, app will download updates silently and perform the update when it's restarted. Is there any method I can let the app update on the very first time opening it?

Have tried adding a button which triggers

`codePush.sync({ updateDialog: true, installMode: codePush.InstallMode.IMMEDIATE });`

with the default checkFrequence: on-app-start .

It works when there's a new update available. However, if I just installed the app, and click the button to trigger `sync()`, then nothing happens. Console log shows:

```
[CodePush] Installing update.
[CodePush] Update is installed and will be run on the next app restart.
[CodePush] Checking for update.
```

Seems like the app first downloaded an update, and then when I call sync(), it just stuck.

Is there any way I can install that downloaded update immediately?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: To me it seems your app should download and install the update on app start? Is this happening for you? The sync button may be a separate issue due to the frequency setting. Can you please try to clarify the question whether you are having a problem with the initial app load update or the sync button update? Thanks.

Comment: @Marklar Thanks for the reply! Did more research and found that Apple doesn't allow app using dialog to prompt user updates, thus the only option left is the sync button. But I don't want to set `checkFrequency` to manual as I still want the download automatically happen in background, I just want this sync button as an additional approach. However, when clicking button, `sync()` stuck on app first install and start, as described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark your update mandatory and that should accomplish what you are looking for. Internally, CodePush actually has two different paths for processing updates. Setting a release to mandatory is equivalent to setting InstallMode to IMMEDIATE and will force the update to be installed right away.